# Root Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have rooted my Samsung Galaxy S5 using Odin to first download (Philz Touch) Recovery, then downloaded Custom Rom 'Omega'.

My first question is if I unrooted it, would I get my Warranty back? 
Second, how can I unroot it?

Third, before I rooted my phone it used to lag a lot and the battery used to drain fast. When I used to open my battery settings, it showed me that (Android System) was draining my battery. I did factory format, and still the same thing. I did everything from Force close unwanted apps to turning off unneeded options (GPS, Mobile Data, Bluetooth) and it did not improve. Then I decided to root my phone, and nothing improved. What should I do?

My Phone is SM-G900F, 4.4.2 Kitkat, bought it from overseas and now using it in the US.

Comment: You've asked three questions here. This site works best when you ask each question in a separate question post. That way, people can answer whichever of your questions they know the answer to.

Answer (score 2):

No. A warranty is a legal agreement between you and the manufacturer. You can't break a contract and expect to "undo" it as if it were a typing mistake in an email.

Answer (score 0):

if you rooted your phone and want to unroot it now, you can do it. And you still have the warranty. For unrooting, you can search some other free tools for help.

Then, after rooting, you can use some battery life improve apps. This is one of the most benefits for rooting, remember that? The only reason that your device still drains a lot is that you have not exploited the utmost function of your rooted phone.

Plus, I enjoyed my rooted One Plus very much, freely remove the preinstalled apps, and improve my battery life sooo much.

Hope you can solve your problem soon.

Answer (score 0):

I just start by saying that my english is a little bit bad!

First: No! when your warrenty is void, it will be void!
To find out if your warrenty is void, just reboot into Download mode, press volume up, read the text in upper left corner. If the line that says something about warrenty looks like 0x0, your warrenty is NOT void. If it's like 0x1, your warrenty is dead!

Second: You can use Kies! Samsung's program for computer to update, backup, restore and get the original software to your phone back ;)

Third: I'm sorry, but I can't help :/